# JQuery, retrieve children and grandchildren

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

Let's say I have a JQuery object which has (or points to) such a structure:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="grandchild1">
      // ... grandchild can also have children
    </div>
    // ... and so on of grandchildren
  </div>
  <div id="child2">

  </div>
  // .... and so on
</div>
```

Is there possibility to get plain array of elements (JQuery object) from my object like this:

```
['parent', 'child1', 'child2', ..., 'grandchild1', ...]
```

Thanks

P.S. Please notice that it can't be selector something like this $('div > div'), because I already have
JQuery object and only from this object I need take stuff.

Comment: I'm curious to know what you mean by *"...get plain array of elements (JQuery object)..."*. Which did you want? An Array, or a jQuery object?

Comment: jQuery object is actually array, right? I meant that I want to get parent and all nested elements

Comment: No, a jQuery object is sometimes called an Array-like object, but it isn't an actual Array.

Comment: I'm new to jQuery so I can't be specific, I often treat jQuery object as an array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can retrieve children and grandchildren using the [`*`](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) selector. The items will be returned in tree order. You can then get a plain array of elements using [`jQuery.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

```js
$(function() {
  let a = $("#wrapper")
    .find("*")
    .addBack() // add the previous match i.e. #wrapper itself to the collection
    .toArray();
  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
      <div id="grandchild1">
        <div class="level-4"></div>
        <div class="level-4"></div>
        <div class="level-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
      <div class="level-3"></div>
      <div class="level-3"></div>
      <div class="level-3"></div>
      <div class="level-3">
        <div class="level-4"></div>
        <div class="level-4"></div>
        <div class="level-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is an overkill but useful if you are more interested in iterating the *hierarchy* using recursion:

```js
function recursiveIterate($node, array) {
  $node.children().each(function() {
    array.push(this);
    recursiveIterate($(this), array);
  });
}
$(function() {
  var a = [];
  recursiveIterate($("#wrapper"), a);
  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
      <div id="grandchild1">
        <div class="level-4"></div>
        <div class="level-4"></div>
        <div class="level-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
      <div class="level-3"></div>
      <div class="level-3"></div>
      <div class="level-3"></div>
      <div class="level-3">
        <div class="level-4"></div>
        <div class="level-4"></div>
        <div class="level-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The recursiveIterate function is very helpful for me, because i'm not good at recursion, thanks

Comment: @megas: first example will give you a *flat* array; second can be used to create an array of arrays (not demonstrated).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`toArray()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) method to make your jQuery object into an Array.

```
var arr = my_obj.toArray();
```

...or the [`get()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method if you don't pass it any arguments.

```
var arr = my_obj.get();
```

---

If I've misunderstood, and you're pointing to the *root* of the structure, and need to get its descendants, use the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method  method.

```
var descendants = my_obj.find('div');
```

---

jQuery [has many traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) that let you get around the DOM structure from a given point.

---

If you *only* wanted children and grandchildren, and nothing deeper, do this:

```
var two_generations = my_obj.find('> div > div');
```

This will give you `div` elements only 2 generations deep.

If you don't want to limit it to `div` elements, do this:

```
var two_generations = my_obj.find('> * > *');
```

Comment: And I believe you mean `$('parent,parent *').toArray()`, correct?

Comment: @patrick dw, will this get the children and grandchildren also?

Comment: @kmb385: The question title and text seem a little out of sync, but I updated my answer in case OP is actually referring only to a particular node, and not the entire set.

Answer (score 1):

Hey man I'm pretty new here and I was having a similar brain fart. To get the grandchildren, I suggest using the .children() approach:

```
$('#parent') //selects the parents
$('#parent').children() //selects the children
$('#parent').children().children() //selects the grandchildren
```