# ol outside of table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just try a table with `<ol>` as list elements with which it is possible to insert new table row.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <ol id="list">
      <li><tr><td>row</td><td>row</td><td>row</td></tr></li>
  </ol>       
</tbody>
```

However, I have the problem that the  element appear outside of my tables. When I add dynamically content via `.append()`, the formatting is not taken some elements  gets removed.

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yd8dB/1/)

I want to use this  solution for counting currently positions in an "container list".
I got a similar function like the example below for counting my lists, that's working great but the insert into the table does not work properly.

countinglists example: [Nested ordered lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852816/nested-ordered-lists/1852859#1852859)

Maybe its possible to achieve that counting syntax in a table without the `<ol>`? or is there any `<ol>` equivalent?

Comment: You cannot place `<tr>` or `<td>` elements under `<li>`

Comment: that's bad :/ .. any idea to solve something like that?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: semantically, yes. syntactically not (i.e. opened tags get closed). At the end of the day, the outcome depends on the DOM parser and renderer. My chrome console also doesn't say anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some reading on basic HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Here is how it should look...

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="list">
   <tr>
      <td>row</td><td>row</td><td>row</td><td>row</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>row</td><td>row</td><td>row</td><td>row</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>row</td><td>row</td><td>row</td><td>row</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: we know the proper syntax of an table :) but i read know i cant add an <tr> under an <li> element! thats the reason :/

Comment: You cannot. you can create a full list inside a `<td>` element however.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to use CSS counters.

```
table {
  counter-reset: myTableCounter; 
}

thead th:first-child:before {
   display: table-cell;
  content: "";
}

tbody td:first-child:before {
  display: table-cell;
  counter-increment: myTableCounter;
  content: counter(myTableCounter);
}
```

However, when I attempted to do that I found [there were issues with `display: table-cell` generated content](http://jsbin.com/weberuma/1/edit).

You may have to look at [adding additional elements to the table](http://jsbin.com/weberuma/2/) to generate the content inside the first cell of each row.

Answer (score 0):

My question is: what are you trying to achieve? Is this an exercise just to see how much can you stretch the HTML?

For your jsfiddle, the action associated to the click removes some of the HTML tags (at least on my browser) resulting in a `<li>rowrowrow</li>`, so you end up having a rather odd formatted-table. My renderer takes all `<li>` tags added by clicking as the content of a row; if you have only `<li>` tags, the dom parser will likely wrap them into a `<ul>` (it does on mine).

IMHO you don't need to use the `ol` to be able to count stuff. You can do it in jquery afaik. If you insist to use lists, then you probably need to style them and use e.g. `div`s inside (styled too). Emulating a table via a list and divs is madness imho :)

**Update** - for the hierarchical table

My idea would be to have something similar to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27FvD/). I basically styled in the `.sub` and the `.main` classes. However, things get a bit more complex is you need to add some extra columns. In this case, you'd need something like a [treetable](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#examples).

Comment: i want to archive something like my attached picture with an table. where i have an ID for each <tr> element. and where i can add an new entry or an sub-entry. i want to archieve something like an invoice table with sub-counting positions.. Picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qKMRx.jpg .. i like the <ol> counting syntax so if i remove an element or add i can traverse the <ol> and count the index() positions.. maybe there is some other method to solve this :)

Comment: @nmkr.at: for hierarchical tables, you can do it in jquery (manage the hierarchy there) or, [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945460/how-do-i-present-a-tree-in-an-html-table) via showing/hiding columns (and using probably `colspan`)

Comment: the table represents only the content, like the attached picture we need some "containers" where the content=<tr> are placed. so we have an position and index of that "container" to work with. if we delete an container all positions get a new index etc..

Comment: i played around with a div shema, can someone tell me how to traverse the nested and sub-nested elements? i would solve this in making a for loop and check under each "main" entry if there are sub or sub-sub or sub-sub-sub entrys.. what i got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/XzbM3/1/

Comment: For traversal, you need a stack-based (or recursive) function. A recursive example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582253/jquery-retrieve-children-and-grandchildren).